# How can merge 3 cycle and export in one table

Tags: powershell, join, active-directory

How can merge 3 cycle in one script. And export in one table

| server | Name | email | Cluster | TcpTestSucceeded | PingSucceeded | RemoteAddress |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cell 1 | Cell 22 | Cell 11 | Cell 2 | Cell 21 | Cell 13 | Cell 27 |
| Cell 3 | Cell 44 | Cell 33 | Cell 4 | Cell 41 | Cell 33 | Cell 47 |

Getting a list of email by DisplayName in AD

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

 

# path to file

$CSVpatch = "C:\temp\address.csv"

# Get

$result = Import-Csv -Path $CSVpatch -Delimiter ";" -Encoding Default | ForEach-Object {

    $server = $_.server

        Get-ADUser -Filter "DisplayName -eq '$($_.name)'" -Properties DisplayName, EmailAddress |

    Select-Object @{Name = 'server'; Expression = {$server}},

                  @{Name = 'name'; Expression = {$_.DisplayName}},

                  @{Name = 'email'; Expression = {$_.EmailAddress}}

}

# format and export

$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# export


$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\table.csv' -Encoding Default  -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Getting a list of Cluster by Description in AD

```
# path to file 

$CSVpatch = "C:\temp\address.csv"

# Get

$result = Import-Csv -Path $CSVpatch -Delimiter ";" -Encoding Default | ForEach-Object {

    $server = $_.server
   
 Get-ADComputer -Identity $server -Properties * |

    Select-Object @{Name = 'server'; Expression = {$server}},

                  @{Name = 'Cluster'; Expression = {$_.Description}}

                     

}

# format and export

$result |  ft -AutoSize

# export

$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\table.csv' -Encoding Default  -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Checking the availability of the server on a specific port, ping and ip

```
# path to file

$CSVpatch = "C:\temp\address.csv"

# Get

$result = Import-Csv -Path $CSVpatch -Delimiter ";" -Encoding Default | ForEach-Object {

    $server = $_.server

       

 Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $server -Port 13000 |

    Select-Object @{Name = 'server'; Expression = {$server}},

                  @{Name = 'TcpTestSucceeded'; Expression = {$_.TcpTestSucceeded}},

                  @{Name = 'PingSucceeded'; Expression = {$_.PingSucceeded}},

                  @{Name = 'RemoteAddress'; Expression = {$_.RemoteAddress}}

                         

}

# format and export

$result |  ft -AutoSize

# export

$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\table.csv' -Encoding Default  -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
```

Comment: Thanks! JoinModule resolfe the problem.

Comment: My reputation is low and i don't upvote your post. Please answer this question and I will accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)), you might join multiple tables (based on a common property) at once:

```
$Result1 = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
server, Name,   email
Cell1,  Cell22, Cell11
Cell3,  Cell44, Cell33
'@

$Result2 = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
server, Cluster
Cell1,  Cell2
Cell3,  Cell4
'@

$Result3 = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
server, TcpTestSucceeded, PingSucceeded, RemoteAddress
Cell1,  Cell21,           Cell13,        Cell27
Cell3,  Cell41,           Cell33,        Cell47
'@

$Result1 |Join $Result2 -on Server |Join $Result3 -on Server |Format-Table

server Name   email  Cluster TcpTestSucceeded PingSucceeded RemoteAddress
------ ----   -----  ------- ---------------- ------------- -------------
Cell1  Cell22 Cell11 Cell2   Cell21           Cell13        Cell27
Cell3  Cell44 Cell33 Cell4   Cell41           Cell33        Cell47
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here.  Do you have a sample from the CSV files?
**C:\temp\address.csv**

That would help a lot. Based on your code you have at least these two columns:

- Name       <- AD User Displayname
- Server     <- AD Computer Name

I generally do not use Displayname as a joint or a lookup value as you can have duplicates.  It's a bad practice.  You should use sAMaccountName or UPN instead.

Once I see the sample I can help you.

Comment: Need Displayname, because Displayname
is unloaded from another database

C:\temp\address.csv
server;name
AM-server;Simeon Yonchev
MS-server;Abhijit Khandagale
RR-server;Ruchi Jha
PA-server;Simeon Khandagale
NI-server;Ruchi Abhijit

C:\Temp\table.csv
server;name;email;Cluster;TcpTestSucceeded;PingSucceeded;RemoteAddress
AM-server;Simeon Yonchev;mail1@ms.com;;;;
MS-server;Abhijit Khandagale;mail2@ms.com;;;;
RR-server;Ruchi Jha;mail3@ms.com;;;;
PA-server;Simeon Khandagale;mail4@ms.com;;;;
NI-server;Ruchi Abhijit;mail5@ms.com;Failover cluster virtual network name account;;;